# Avoiding call for the Js file which has been already included?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-cache

i hav included below js file in my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<s:url value="/script/customer.js?ver=1.2.3"/>'></script>
```

Jsp file contains hyperlink on which ajax call is made and response of that call contains  again above code to include js file.

Ideally no call should be made for the same js file again they are cached by browser.Then i inspected in firebug and found out
below url is bit diefferent when i.e it includse  extra parameter _=1360589976328. I  do not want to make the call for the
same js file again if it has been included.(i can not remove from ajax response jsp because of some reason). I think problem
is this extra paramter, probably becoz of which  call is made again.

Any idea why extra param is appended or double call is
made to include the js file when it already exists in browser?

```
http://localhost:8080/custModule/script/customer.js?ver=1.2.3?ver=4.5.8&_=1360589976328
```

Comment: You mean it already had been cached, not *included* in the same page? And your problem is more related to jsp than to javascript?

Comment: How is ajax related to this? If it's relevant, please show us the code you are using for it.